# How to Abort Thread Tcp Connection

Tags: c#, multithreading

I start to learn about thread i use with success but i cant abort thread 
program cannot successfully end.

Please help how can i abort ?

```
for (int i = 0; i < dtProd.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                sayacno = dtProd.Rows[i].ItemArray[2].ToString();
                komut = "<25></25>";
                Connection TCP = new Connection("as","sd","fd","gd");
                Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(TCP.Bagla));
                t.IsBackground = true;
                t.Start();
                threads.Add(t);
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }

            for (int t = 0; t < threads.Count; t++)
            {
                try
                {
                    threads[t].Join();
                    threads[t].Abort();
                }
                catch (ThreadAbortException tx)
                {
                    Console.Write(tx.ToString());
                }            
            }
```

Comment: `threads[t].Join();` will cause the calling thread to block until `threads[t]` thread has ended.  I wouldn't expect it to ever get to the Abort line.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've the change below calls from:

```
   threads[t].Join();
   threads[t].Abort();
```

to:

```
   threads[t].Abort();
   threads[t].Join();
```